# Ввод строки любой длинны scanf

Tags: c, malloc, scanf

Есть задача: получить строку и выдать её в обратном порядке. Условия: длины строк и слов неограниченны. Нужно использовать списки.

Меня интересует как грамотно подсчитывать кол-во вводимых символов что бы потом выделить память для строки?

Создавать фиксированный "буффер" не вариант (оно и видно из условия).

UPD: scanf необязателен

UPD 24.05 00:16 msk: сделал так крч и всё, раз просто строку хз как обозначить чтоб из неё потом сделать список слов

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct str{
        int c;
        struct str *next;
};

void reverse_str(struct str *list);
void free_list(struct str *list);

int main()
{
        int c;
        struct str *main = NULL,  *sub = NULL;
        while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
                switch(c){
                        case '\n':
                                reverse_str(main);
                                free_list(main);
                                putchar(c);
                                break;
                        default:
                                struct str *tmp = malloc(sizeof(*tmp));
                                tmp->c = c;
                                tmp->next = NULL;
                                if(sub){
                                        sub->next = tmp;
                                        sub = sub->next;
                                } else
                                        main = sub = tmp;
                }
        }
        return 0;
}

void reverse_str(struct str *list)
{
        if(!list)
                return;
        reverse_str(list->next);
        putchar(list->c);
}

void free_list(struct str *list)
{
        if(list){
                struct str *tmp = list;
                list = list->next;
                free(tmp);
        }
}
```

Тупа список кодов символов.

Comment: Никак, считываете в цикле по 1 символу пока не дойдете до конца строки. Буфер или сами увеличиваете динамически, или используете `std::string` или `std::vector<char>`. А обязательно `scanf()` использовать? Гораздо проще `std::getline()`, которая сразу строку помещает в `std::string`.

Comment: @DmitryK Язык С, так что... По делу: читать, постепенно наращивая динамически выделяемую память. Или записывать в файл — может, строка такая длинная, что и в оперативной памяти не поместится, как знать? :)

Comment: @Harry Да, на метку-то я и не обратил внимание! Но как же неудобно!

Comment: @Harry, realloc не вариант. Ибо по книге и по задаче еще не дошли до realloc'a. Недопустим getline да и вообще Си++, никакого std, vector... :) Если задача есть, значит как-то решаема без вышеперечисленного ) Функции getline я вообще в книге не видел )

Comment: gcc [getline](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) (GNU gcc реализован практически для всех компьютеров, выпускаемых в мире)

Comment: @avp, getline не вариант.

Comment: @nx4n, если это вам говорит преподователь в учебных целях, то стоит реализовать самому. Если вам говорят, что realloc тоже использовать нельзя, то сделайте на списке. Тем более, вы сами пишете, что выдать ее в обратном порядке. Вот для этого отлично подойдет список фрагментов фиксированной длины, организованный как стек

Comment: Для общего развития -- [реализация getline](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/stdio/getline.c) (если хотите стать программистом можете поковыряться в коде этой либы)

Comment: @avp, точно, можно же просто малокнуть строки по 5 допустим в структуре и сканфом в них фиксированной длинны заносить их, спасибо)) так ведь имеете ввиду?))

Comment: Но ведь  там потребуется потом и сами строки в структурах реверсить, больше кода и т.п. Что в итоге лучше? Посимвольно структуру создавать или фрагментами?

Comment: @nx4n, да, можно scanf-ом, но imho проще и эффективней fgetc (конечно, элементом списка должен быть фрагмент разумного размера, скажем страница (обычно 4К). Соответственно в структуре элемента списка будет сама память, размер (насколько заполнена) и указатель на след.)

Answer (score 1):

Остается предположить, что от вас хотят чего-то [такого](https://ideone.com/fH9i1w), если уж даже работа с памятью неизвестна...

```
#include <stdio.h>

void get_out_char()
{
    char c;
    scanf("%c",&c);
    if (c != '\n')
    {
        get_out_char();
        putchar(c);
    }
}

int main()
{
    get_out_char();
}
```

Или без `scanf` —

```
void get_out_char()
{
    int c = getchar();
    if (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
    {
        get_out_char();
        putchar(c);
    }
}
```

Только вы бы сразу же давали точное условие, а то получается [вот так](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7F80U-pPVk)...

Comment: Не понял. Что значит работа с памятью неизвестна?

Comment: malloc можно использовать. Нужно ввести строку и превратить её в список по словам(это я знаю как сделать и как выделить память для слова в структуре). Я не знаю как и во что строку вводимую положить что бы четко была выделена память под неё.  Как посчитать кол-во введенных символов, выделить память и положить в неё эту строку для дальнейшей работы с ней.

Comment: Знаете, заколебало. "*Дайте воды напиться, а то так есть хочется, что и переночевать негде*". Если вам напишут со списками — выяснится, что нужны, например, не двусвязные, а односвязные списки? Кстати, откуда вдруг требование о списках и почему его не было раньше? (Впрочем, ответ ничего не изменит — отвечать на ваш вопрос я больше не буду, менять вопрос после ответа — все равно как сесть играть в очко и, набрав 22, срочно поменять правила игры: теперь выигрывает тот, у кого 22! Я так не играю...)

Comment: какая разница списки или нет? Нужно ввести строку, выделить память для неё и работать с ней через эту выделенную память - вот и всё. Что дальше со строкой делать не имеет значения, я не задавал вопрос "Как её перевернуть".

Comment: Я прошу прощения если сбил вас с толку, дал мало информации и подпортил настроение. Но я хочу узнать лишь об этом. Возможно ли это или нет? Или это как раз таки через списки и делается? Не нужно решение в виде кода, достаточно краткого объяснения. Не ответите, ну и ладно, всего доброго, понимаю.

Answer (score 0):

Вот, вспомнил:

```
char *response = NULL;
size_t len;
getline(&response, &len, stdin);
```

`getline` сама выделяет буфер динамически под необходимый объем.
Потом буфер надо освобождать `free(response);`

Comment: Да, но что делать, если компилятор не GCC?...

Comment: @Harry Возможно я чего-то не знаю о компиляторах, но `getline()` объявлена в `<stdio.h>` вместе со `scanf()`. Если можно использовать `scanf()`, то можно и `getline()`.

Comment: Где? В VC этого нет. В стандарте языка С ее тоже вроде не видно (смотрел "Язык С. Справочник" и "Rationale for International Standard—Programming Languages—C Revision 5.10". Кстати, см. https://stackoverflow.com/q/13112784/9123401: *getline() is not in the C standard library, but is a POSIX 2008 extension*.

Comment: @Harry Соглашусь. Был введен в заблуждение описанием на cppreference.com [https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/getline], где написано что она объявлена в stdio.h

Comment: getline не вариант

Answer (score 0):

Вводим символы и считаем их.

Что-то похожее на это:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char* symbols = NULL;
    int count = 0;
    char c;
    printf("input symbols: ");
    do{
        scanf("%c", &c);
        if(c == '\n')
            break;
        symbols = (char*)realloc(symbols, ++count * sizeof(char));
        symbols[count - 1] = c;
    }while(1);
    
    printf("you wrote: %s\n", symbols);
    printf("you count: %d", count);
    
    
 for(int i=count; i>=0; --i)
    printf("s1: %c\n", symbols[i]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Терминирующий нуль не добавлен в строку `symbols`, следовательно поведение кода `printf("you wrote: %s\n", symbols)` не определено.

Comment: symbols[sizeof(symbols)]='\0'; Есть и другие варианты.

Comment: Так как тип переменной `symbols` — это `char*`, то `sizeof(symbols)` всегда равен `sizeof(char*)`. Данный способ вставки терминирующего нуля не зависит от длины строки, а значит ошибочен.

Comment: Вроде 0 выводит - symbols[count]='\0';

Comment: @wololo Может есть вариант после ввода обратиться к буфферу? И из него достать как целую строку? При вводе символов ведь в буффере (каком-то) всё хранится

Comment: Так как массив `symbols` состоит из `count` элементов, и индексация начинается с нуля, то здесь `symbols[count]='\0'` доступ к несуществующему элементу массива. Поведение программы не определено.

Comment: Только надо бы проверять возврат из `realloc`.

Comment: Будет тормозить на длинных строках.